# How to change the text color of .jsp file instead of only black color in STS 4.12.0?

Tags: java, jsp, sts

**My JSP file like this**

```
My JSP file text only in simple black color
```

[image]

**But I want like this which is something colorful and much more readable.**

[image]

Comment: Which editor do you use?

Comment: STS(Spring Tool Suite)

Comment: STS is based on Eclipse (at least it used to be).  It could be that you created a "file" rather than a "JSP" so STS isint applying syntax highlighting to the file.  You should be able to set the file type of your file, though its been a long time since I have used STS, if your file has the correct file extension for a jsp and its still not being highlighted, try right clicking the file, or perhaps looking for a setting in the project settings.  A more hacky way might be to use STS `file` menu to create a jsp and cut and paste the contents of one file to the other.

Comment: Please don't show code as image but better copy/paste